# does phrase “keep something from sb.” has some hidden information？

Tags: grammar, phrases, reading, comprehension

> "The Farewell," which features as predominantly Asian cast, tells the
>   story of a young woman named Billi (Awkwafina) whose family decides to
>   keep news of a terminal diagnosis from the family's elder matriarch,
>   Billi's grandmother Nai Nai (Shuzhen Zhao).

[Awkwafina makes Golden Globes history](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/01/05/entertainment/awkwafina-golden-globes/index.html)

I am doing some reading practice. But i was confused by this sentence.

> " keep news of a terminal diagnosis from the family's elder matriarch"

I know the phrase means don't tell sb. something.
The problem is don't tell grandmother what?
whose terminal diagnosis? Billi or Grandmother?

The answer tell me is Gradmother's terminal diagnosis. But why?

Am i missing some important information?

Comment: The actual text you've cited says nothing whatsoever about ***whose*** terminal diagnosis is being kept secret from grandma. It's probably not grandma's next-door neighbour, some national politician, or her favourite rap artist, but *nothing in the text itself* gives us any clues on that score.

Comment: All the sentence says is that a terminal condition has been diagnosed and grandma is not to be told.  That's it.  Whoever has the condition is not evident.

Comment: Remember that auxiliary verbs require an infinitive verb complement.

Comment: Anyone can check [the IMDB synopsis](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8637428/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) *(A Chinese family discovers **their grandmother** has only a short while left to live and decide to keep her in the dark*. But I don't think it's even meaningful to VTC as POB - even the most minimal "research" should establish that *we have no way of knowing* just from the actual text as cited above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Because my teacher and schoolmate all told me it's grandmother who was been diagnosed. That makes me so confused.